# Length limit on Hadoop config property value

Tags: java, hadoop

What is the length limit (if any) on the value of a Hadoop configuration property? And is this limit itself configurable?

I'm not talking about the default properties, this will be a custom property that I'll be passing along to my map-reduce application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit is the size of a string in Java since they are all stored in a `java.util.Properties` object